# Android : How to load images in Horizontal Scroll View only it is visible

Tags: android

I want to add some images to an Horizontal Scroll View and want these images to be loaded only when the user scroll the horizontal scroll and the image come to the visible area .

I built a custom layout that extends linear layout to hold the image

And tried to add the loading of the image to

onFocusChanged

onWindowVisibilityChanged

onWindowFocusChanged

but nothing is working

any help ??

Comment: editing your question and adding the code you are using might help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem is better solved with a `RecyclerView`. It'll handle horizontal scrolling, image loading when views becomes visible, and recycling views for better performance over large data sets. Among other things.

There are tons of tutorials out there, find one that suits you're style and dive in!